# 20.04 - How to remove/resize white space arround Desktop Icons

Tags: updates, 20.04, icons, desktop-icons

After I upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, I got a couple of unspected surprises and saw that the icons on the ubuntu's Desktop have a white box/space arround the icon that profoundly annoys me. (as you can see in the image below) [image] On top of that it seems that I can't select multiple folders and move them around freely.

Is there any way to solve this problem??